# Windows phone s.o.s mode

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone

I'm a newbie windows phone programmer and I'm developing an app that uses the phone's LED flash as a flashlight.

Using C#, how do I achieve the S.O.S mode, where I make the LED flash blink continuously, upon clicking a button?

Answer (score 1):

In your class declare a bool variable to false, then in the event handler of the button use an while condition like this
    var blink = false;

In your event handler

```
blink = !blink;
while(blink)
    {
    PhotoCamera cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
    cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;
    await Task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;
    }
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question... your "change sos colors" comment is precisely what the OP doesn't know how to do.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque oh, I see. Let me just edit my code!

Comment: @ThomasLevesque this is what I got with some googling, we'll see if it works!

Comment: It doesn't turn the flash on and off; it just enables the flash when taking a picture. It does nothing as long as the camera is not triggered.